# Assign instance of 2d array to index in 3d array

Tags: c++

I have a 2d and 3d array declared as follows:

```
unsigned char twoDArray[2][2];
unsigned char threeDArray[5][2][2];
```

I populated my "twoDArray" with the four values that I need, and now I want to place this into the first location of the threeDArray:

```
threeDArray[0] = twoDArray;
```

I am getting an error message of "Cannot assign to an array type unsigned char[2][2]."  Is there any way to do this assignment, aside from looping through the 2d array and placing each value into the 3d array one at a time at location threeDArray[0][row][col] (where row and col change to access each element in my 2d array)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::memcpy(threeDarray[0], twoDarray, sizeof twoDarray);`. But this is wasteful if it will be done frequently or with large arrays, in which case an alternate algorithm that does not require assigning to subarrays should be sought.

Comment: Using `std::array` instead of raw array will let you do this, using a simple assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++11, you can use `std::array<>` instead of c-style arrays which support assignment via `operator=`.

`std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 2>, 2> twoDArray{};`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this really depends on, whenever you can use C++11 or not.
If you have to rely on pre C++11 you have to do this, like you would do this in C:
Using `memcpy` to copy the memory of the array into the other one. This is error prone, since it lacks type safety, so one wrong number and boom *undefined behaviour*.

With C++11 you can use `std::array` which makes everything easier, more readable and more safe, I made you a solution for both ways:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <array>

int main() {
    {
        unsigned char twoDArray[2][2];
        unsigned char threeDArray[5][2][2];
        std::memcpy(threeDArray[0], twoDArray, 2 * 2);

    }
    {
        using oneDArrayT = std::array<unsigned char, 2>;
        using twoDArrayT = std::array<oneDArrayT,2>;
        twoDArrayT twoDArray{};
        std::array<twoDArrayT,5> threeDArray{};
        threeDArray[0] = twoDArray;
    }

}
```